# How to open an activity as a new one in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am working on a project that has as an idea to create folders an inside them to create todo lists.
I have created two diffrerent list activities, one for the folders and one for the todo list.
I want when i  click on the folder title to be redirected on a todo list. I have used the intent method but when i am clicking on a folder i am moved on the same todo list. How can i change that to be moved on the todo list activiy but to be opened as a new one? Also i am using an if statment for each position of the folder title, what if i dont know how many folders the user is going to create, how am i supposed to know how many if stamtment i am going to create?

The todo list activity:

```
public class viewTasksActivity extends ListActivity {

private Button addButton;
private AnyNoteManagerApplication app;
private TaskListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tasks_main);


    setUpViews();
    app = (AnyNoteManagerApplication)getApplication();
    adapter = new TaskListAdapter(app.getCurrentTasks(), this);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    adapter.forceReload();

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    adapter.toggleTaskCompleteAtPosition(position);

}

private void setUpViews() {
    addButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_task_button);
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(viewTasksActivity.this, AddTaskActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}

}
```

The Folder List aCtivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private Button addButton;
private AnyNoteManagerApplication app;
private FolderListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    setUpViews();
    app = (AnyNoteManagerApplication)getApplication();
    adapter = new FolderListAdapter(app.getCurrentFolders(), this);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    adapter.forceReload();

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    if(position == 0) {
        //code specific to first list item    
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, viewTasksActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
    if(position == 1) {
        //code specific to first list item    
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, viewTasksActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }


    /*Intent taskList = new Intent(MainActivity.this, viewTasksActivity.class);

    startActivity(taskList);*/
}

private void setUpViews() {
    addButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_folder_button);

    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddFolderActivity.class);

        startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}

}
```

Thank you everyone in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should open up new Activities. I think that your data in the other activities aren't being updated, that is why it seems that new Activities aren't being opened. You can do this to add a value to your intent:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key", "some string value");
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in your opened activity to get the value you sent:

```
String sent_value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");
```

**EDIT**

You can add all your list view values to an array, and in your list onItemClick you can just get the item that you clicked on like this:

```
list_values.get(position);
```